# Excerpt of client-side javascript shows up as text in body of Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

We're developing a plugin for a client on a Wordpress site.  And, for some reason, an excerpt of the clientside javascript of the plugin appears as raw text in the body of the page.

Here is an image of the page with its markdown:
[image]

Entire shortcode script:

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Cata Employee
   Plugin URI:
   description: Employee Viewer
   ...
```

https://pastebin.com/iFiJT0rM

strangely enough, even when removing the clientside javascript, the script *still* appears as text on the page after a couple refreshes.  My guess is it's something cached, and my coworker suggested it's being caused by SEO stuff of some sort.

**What we've tried:**

- Changing the plugin from a Cornerstone Element to a Shortcode
- Adding a function to the script that hides the text (only some of the lines of the text are in targetable elements, and they share a direct parent with the plugin itself, so we can't just hide the whole tree)
- Making the plugin the only element on the page

Might seem redundant, but desired behavior needs to be explicitly stated:

**Observed Behavior:**
A snip of the clientside javascript appears as text on the page

**Desired Behavior:**
Not having a snip of the clientside javascript appear as text on the page

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated; we really have no idea what's causing this

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing how that part of the HTML document is generated.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's what we're trying to find out; we don't know what's making it either, and were hoping it was something someone else had experienced before.

Comment: OK - but I'm a little puzzled because you mentioned that the script is part of a plugin you're developing (and which you obviously want ran on the page as Javascript, rather than output as text), which presumably implies you're putting it on the page somewhere in your (PHP) code? Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The thing is, it _is_ being run as Javascript; the script runs perfectly fine.  But it appears that something else, outside of our plugin's JavaScript and PHP, is looking at the script tag on the page, copying it, and pasting it as text outside of the plugin.  It's been perplexing the whole team since Thursday

Comment: Oh right - then unfortunately all I can say is "have fun debugging that", I can't help without seeing the whole project, and being paid for my time to comb through it (and no, I'm not seriously offering). There's a reason I was happy to move away from WordPress development (after not very long doing it)...

Comment: Honestly, that's fair.  Thanks for looking anyway

Comment: SEO “stuff of some sort” doesn’t make code magically appear in pages after it’s deleted. If you can still see it after you delete it from the files, then you must be seeing a cached version. As for why it’s appearing - without seeing your setup or any of your code, its impossible for us to tell... we can’t help debug code we can’t see! Have you tried disabling your other plugins one by one and testing with a default theme to try to identify *where* the problem is arising?

Comment: >just added a pastebin link to the entire script.  The most puzzling thing is, we've zipped and moved this plugin between different sites with entirely different setups, and it still happened.  So, we're not sure what, but we think there's something in our plugin that's triggering that strangely-specific excerpt to show up as text